# jQuery problems with parent().remove()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table, parent

I am trying to clone and remove a table with jQuery, without success. 
Here is an example, the table I want to operate:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="6" class="linha_space"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3">Dummy1</td>
        <td colspan="3">Dummy2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2"><input name="aperf_cursos[]" type="text" /></td>
        <td colspan="2"><input name="aperf_entidades[]" type="text" /></td>
        <td colspan="2"><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="adicionar" onclick="add(this);"><img src="./images/add.gif" /></a><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remover" onclick="remove(this);" style="display: none;"><img src="./images/delete.gif" /></a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="6" class="linha_space"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Now, the javascript functions add() and remove():

```
function add(o){
    var o = $(o);
    var tr = o.parent().parent().parent();
    tr.after(tr.clone()); 
    tr.find('.adicionar').remove();
    tr.find('.remover').show();
    tr.next().find('input, select').val('');
    tr.next().find('.remover').hide();
}
function remove(o){
    var o = $(o);
    o.parent().parent().parent().remove(); 
}
```

add(this) works perfectly, but the remove(this) is not working, it removes just my "delete.gif" image. What am I doing wrong please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/siva_hari/jKCWr/).

I used jQuery for what you need.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="6" class="linha_space"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3">Dummy1</td>
        <td colspan="3">Dummy2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2"><input name="aperf_cursos[]" type="text" /></td>
        <td colspan="2"><input name="aperf_entidades[]" type="text" /></td>
        <td colspan="2"><a href="#" class="adicionar">Add</a><a href="#" class="remover" style="display: none;">Delete</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="6" class="linha_space"></td>
    </tr>
</table>

$(function() {
    $(document).on('click', '.adicionar', function(event){
        var o = $(event.target);
        var tr = o.closest('table');
        tr.after(tr.clone()); 
        tr.find('.adicionar').remove();
        tr.find('.remover').show();
        tr.next().find('input, select').val('');
        tr.next().find('.remover').hide();
    });

    $(document).on('click', '.remover', function(event){
        var o = $(event.target);
        var table = $(o.closest('table')); 
        table.remove();        
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this parent.parent.parent madness (it's madness, yes it is) why don't you use

element.closest("tr")

to find the row it's in?

This approach will work consistently.

Comment: Hi codenoire!

I want to remove the entire table, not only the row (tr). Maybe i'm not figuring out how closest("tr") will help me in this issue.

Comment: Aha!  Then use element.closest("table") -- got it?  The closest function does the same as parent, but stops at the first parent element that matches the selector.  http://api.jquery.com/closest/